# Windows IOT task not run on startup (but it runs on manual command)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I created a `.bat` file which execute `.ps1` file.
Then I [added](https://iot-developer.net/windows-iot/windows-iot-general/os-tasks/task-scheduler) scheduled tasks:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONSTART /TN MyApp /TR "c:\Projects\MyApp\Startup.bat" /RU SYSTEM
```

and power down Raspberry Pi 3B+. When I supply power again, my ASP.NET Core 3.0 app is not running.
If I connect to Raspberry Pi power shell and run

```
schtasks /Run /TN MyApp
```

application runs (web page is displayed).

Is there any logs, where I could found what went wrong?
Has anybody have any idea, why task is not ran on application start up?

Every post I found mention that task also doesn't run/execute if tried manually. But this is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ETW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/eventtracing) on Windows IoT Core to trace the event log for schedule tasks. The Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler provider can be used to track the detail info when a scheduled task run or stop.

[image]

BTW, I'm not sure what's the content in your Startup.bat and *.ps1 file. I created the files with following content, it works for me.

**Startup.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell -executionpolicy bypass -File "C:\Projects\MyApp\start.ps1"
```

**start.ps1**

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Projects\MyApp\NetCoreWebApp.exe"
```

Before you created the scheduled task, you can test the scripts step by step to ensure the script works fine.